# ordering profile 2 module profile type tabs

Tags: users

i am using profile2 module, i create some profile types, but in profile section in admin/structure/profiles   i can't ordering them,is this profile default or this is only my problem?
i means if i add another `profile type` it just come below of anothers and any feature to ordering them

can i ordering them in `form_alter`?

```
function hook_form_alter($form,$form_state){
   change order of theme here ??? how
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default profile2 module not cosidered any ordering of it's profile types.
if you want to change default ordering of them you have some  solution.
create a `template file` for `user_profile` . 
Another way is ordering them with form alter
in your custom module

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form,$form_state) {
 if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
     // do this for all your profile types
     $form['profile_yourprofiletype']['#weight'] = 'your optional order';
   }
 }
```